# Azure Metric Alert - Corresponding Logs

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-eventgrid

I have created an Alert Rule in Event Grid for Dropped Events, alert works fine and I get the email, but neither in the Alert email or when I go and look at it in the Azure portal it shows me the actual error, like which subscription(s) had the failure and the error text (in my case I actually stopped one of the Functions that was subscribing one of the events to test the Alert)

In the Diagnostic Settings of Event Grid, I have set the logs to be sent to Log Analytics workspace but even after this I see no logs for the corresponding failures, am I missing anything? Is there an easy way to see the logs against a particular Alert?

Answer (score 0):

Azure alerts proactively notify you when important conditions are found in your monitoring data. Log alerts allow users to use a [Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-tutorial) query to evaluate resources logs every set frequency, and fire an alert based on the results.

You can search for the functions app logs under log analytics, check this [Monitoring Azure Functions with Azure Monitor Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp) documentation for the steps to do it.

Azure monitor processes terabytes of customer's log from across the world, which can also cause logs ingestion latency. It can be solved by [optimizing the log alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log-query#how-to-start-writing-an-alert-log-query) queries.